# Next and Previous function on calendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, calendar

I'm trying to create a calendar with the click event next and previous. 
 When the page load, it will load the current month and year. I added next and previous function to go either to next month or previous month when either of these 2 is click. I added a AJAX function which is something like this.

This is my script.

```
$(document).on('click', '#next', function(){

          var d = new Date();
          var m = d.getMonth(); 
          var y = d.getFullYear();

          var str = m + 1;
          var str1 = y;


          if (str=="" )
            {
              document.getElementById("calendar_preview").innerHTML="";
                return;
            } 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {

              if(document.getElementById("calendar_preview") != null) {


                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                  {
                    document.getElementById("calendar_preview").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                  }
              }
            }

          var url = calendar_vars.plugin_url + "?month=" + str +"&"+"year="+str1;

          xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
          xmlhttp.send(); 
  });
```

As you can see, this is only on next function, the next is a span element, so when the user click it, it should add +1 to the month eg,. June to July so on, and when reaching the December to Jan, it will change the year ofcourse.

When the user click the next, the variable $month will catch the value and used it to display the month

These are the variables that will get the values from the first script. The script works only once, currently, it changed June to July but when I click it again, nothing happened. Any idea where I'm missing? Thanks

```
$month = $_GET['month']+1;
$y = $_GET['year'];
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery why are you manually doing the ajax call instead of using $.ajax jquery method

Comment: I simple get the Idea here, http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp
Although there is no database yet, this used a change event and now I'm trying to used click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nothing happens because you're always getting the current data and add 1 to it so it always stays on the second month (the month after the current). to get passed it do the following:

take these codes out of your "click" function and write them before the function:

```
var d = new Date();
var m = d.getMonth(); 
var y = d.getFullYear();
```

so it should look like this:

```
var d = new Date();
var m = d.getMonth(); 
var y = d.getFullYear();

$(document).on('click', '#next', function(){

      var str = m + 1;
      var str1 = y;


      if (str=="" )
        {
          document.getElementById("calendar_preview").innerHTML="";
            return;
        } 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {

          if(document.getElementById("calendar_preview") != null) {


            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
              {
                document.getElementById("calendar_preview").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
              }
          }
        }

      var url = calendar_vars.plugin_url + "?month=" + str +"&"+"year="+str1;

      xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
      xmlhttp.send(); 
});
```

Comment: that sucks.. I've been thinking this very hard, and the problem is the declaration of the variable. THIS WORKS! only have to set few things like when it reach 12 return to 1 and add year and so on.

Comment: yes, sometimes the answer is under our noses and we can not see it because of thinking too much, so it's good to have an outside eye to look for some tiny mistakes like this every once in a while! glad it helped.